Conductance at zero magnetic field in Altshuler–Aronov–Spivak (AAS) oscillations
With Altshuler–Aronov–Spivak (AAS) oscillations, can you have a maximum or minimum in conductance at zero magnetic field?

Possibly relevant information: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210717/174766
